# Refactoring from Hooks to a class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Can you please help with refactoring a bit of code from React Hooks to a class component? I'm new in React and this gives me a hard time. I know that { useState } provides some "getter" and "setter", but don't know how to refactor it to a state with props in a "typical" React class component.

Hooks:

```
export default function App() {
const [counter, setCounter] = useState([]);
}
```

React:

```
class App extends React.Component {
state = {
counter:
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the react [Hooks FAQ page](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-hooks-classes-or-a-mix-of-both):

> **Should I use Hooks, classes, or a mix of both?**
>   When you’re ready, we’d encourage you to start trying Hooks in new components you
>   write. Make sure everyone on your team is on board with using them and
>   familiar with this documentation. We don’t recommend rewriting your
>   existing classes to Hooks unless you planned to rewrite them anyway
>   (e.g. to fix bugs).
>
> You can’t use Hooks inside of a class component, but you can
>   definitely mix classes and function components with Hooks in a single
>   tree. Whether a component is a class or a function that uses Hooks is
>   an implementation detail of that component. **In the longer term, we
>   expect Hooks to be the primary way people write React components**.

to answer your question, the equivalent class component would be:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    counter: [] // equivalent of useState([]);
  }
  ...
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    counter: [...prevState.counter, newelement]
  })) // equivalent of setCounter(counter => [...counter, newelement]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look into this example. This a typical class components for increment/counting .

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { count: 0 }

  increment = () => {
      this.setState({
         count: this.state.count + 1
      });
  }

  render(){
     return(
    <button onClick={this.increment}>+</button>
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

Here is the Hooks implementation of it.

```
 function App(){
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

 const increment = () => {
    setCount(count+1);
  };

  return(
    <button onClick={increment}>+</button>
   );
 }
export default App;
```